# Do we need a [disadvantage] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

When I was writing my question, I tried to find [disadvantage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disadvantage) which does not exist, but then remembered that I might should use [advantage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advantage) instead.

Disadvantage is part of advantage/disadvantage mechanic of 5e and both seems similar, although different enough.

Do we need to create [disadvantage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disadvantage) and synonymize it to [advantage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advantage), in case future askers might stumble into it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Advantage/disadvantage is a single mechanic, so I think it should have one master tag. When [advantage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advantage) was made our tag name character limit was too small for [advantage-and-disadvantage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advantage-and-disadvantage) (26, 1 too many).

Now that we have more characters to use, we should just rename it [advantage-and-disadvantage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advantage-and-disadvantage). That would be findable by typing `disad`..., so we might not need a [disadvantage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disadvantage) tag, but because the new tag would be long, it would probably help to have it as a synonym for those who don't notice “…-and-disadvantage” trailing off the end. That way we'd have:

[advantage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advantage) → **[advantage-and-disadvantage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advantage-and-disadvantage)**
[disadvantage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disadvantage) ↗︎

(Also, if we find that we need to use either of the shorter ones for another game that has completely different things called “advantages” and “disadvantages”, like GURPS does for its chargen pieces, we have the option of breaking the synonyms at that later date.)

Comment: renaming it to this more specific ALSO clears up the generic term advantage that is used for character traits on some other games.

Answer (score -1):

[@SevenSidedDie raises a very good point](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8369/do-we-need-a-disadvantage-tag/8370#8370), but here is a shorter alternative to the long tag he suggested: `(dis)advantage`

This style is frequently used by writers and is prolific in legal documents referencing multiple genders as `(s)he` so that they don't need to write `he and/or she`.

I am not sure how the Tag Search would handle searching `disad` but it should appear for both `dis` as well as `advan`

Comment: I don't know exactly how tag system works, but since I've never encountered parenthese in tag, I assume it doesn't support parenthese in tag?

Comment: From the [help page about tagging](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/tagging): "Avoid punctuation (which can make it difficult to use the tag in a URL)"

Comment: That would have been my ideal tag name, but the system removes things like parentheses when you try to use them in a new tag name. Trying to create a [(dis)advantage] tag by editing a post results in creating a [[tag:disadvantage]] tag instead. We're limited to `[0-9][A-Z][a-z][-.]`