# What is the appropriate way to bring community attention to unacted-on meta consensus?

Tags: support, meta

Just for example, these questions:

1. [Do we need a [disadvantage] tag?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8369/do-we-need-a-disadvantage-tag)
2. [Non-duplicate questions, with opposite correct answers, merged](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8599/non-duplicate-questions-with-opposite-correct-answers-merged)

*(Disclaimer: one was my meta question, and the other one is about my question)*

...seem to have community consensus, and requires action, either from the community or the moderator team. They are, however, yet to be executed (the action, I mean).

**How to gently nudge and remind the community (or moderator) that we need to take the agreed-upon action?**

I'm thinking about doing a minor edit to bump the question back to page 1, but it doesn't seem appropriate. I'm also thinking to custom-flag the question, but that only works for the second type (moderator action needed) post.

What is the appropriate method to accomplish this?

Comment: Just as a note: I recommend against executing the RPG.se community regardless of the time frame. ;)

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I disagree - "Caedite eos. Novit enim Dominus qui sunt eius."

Answer (score 6):

- Usually a meta is pretty effective, whether it needs community attention or diamond moderator attention.
- Flag the thing if it needs diamond moderator attention.
- If it's something regular members can do, you may want to just go ahead and do the thing yourself.
- Poke people in [RPG General Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11).

An example of that first one: in 2014, well before I was a moderator, the WoD community on the site agreed to restructure their tagging. Nothing then happened for a couple of weeks and significant agreement had gathered around one particular option so I poked things into action with [Start retagging the WoD questions! (aka "Editors: the Retaggening")](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5001/start-retagging-the-wod-questions-aka-editors-the-retaggening).

Be sure that decent time has occurred: metas get settled over the course of days, like a week minimum. We also usually wait until a course of action has at least double-figure votes.

When it requires some significant moderator action (e.g. unmerging) the diamond moderator team will assess it to make sure it's actually a good idea first, which can take time as well. I have marked both those questions [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) to indicate we are now doing this.